# mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration

Tags: mysql, migration, version

Trying to install a `mysql8.0` on (not yet supported) `debian 10 (aka "Buster")` system that formerly held `mysql5.5`. Installation ends with:

`mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 
[ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.`

I have no need of any encryption. Also I think I had not used a "keyring" before. My question is: what do I have to do to use mysql? Is it maybe possible to skip the keyring migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the server *did* start, regardless of the ERROR message. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189341/can-an-encrypted-mysql-restart-without-the-keyring-file-on-the-box:

> Yes, mysql will start, but you will receive an error if you try to access the encrypted table.